# Delete using XPath Expression OSB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, osb

I am in a For Each loop in OSB.
The loop is indexed by variable .
I would like to delete node from other xml using the index variable in specific XPath Expression-

```
./GetListResult/SearchList/Item['{$index}']
```

It seems that the XPath does not recognize the index variable. How can I use it to specify which node I want to delete?

I google it and found this -
http://blog.darwin-it.nl/2015/06/index-variables-in-replaceinsertdelete.html

There is solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you try `./GetListResult/SearchList/Item[$index]`?

Comment: tried. It is not valid. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Why not delete using xquery instead?

```
let $old_items := $body/GetListResult/SearchList/Item
let $new_items := remove($old_items, $index)
```